# Set link on resizing banner

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, banner

I want to set a link on the banner which resize according to the width of the screen.

For now I have given link to the complete image like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FGJDn).

I want only the button area "Find out here" to be clickable.

Code

```
<div class="outer">
  <a href="http://google.com/" >
    <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/damg257c3/test.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpaAL).

set `position: absolute` and set `left` `top` in `%` to the `link`

For understanding I have set `opacity: 0.5;` to `link`

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/damg257c3/test.jpg" alt="" />
  <a class="link" href="http://google.com/" ></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.link {
  background: red;
    display: block;
    height: 12%;
    left: 24%;
    opacity: 0.5;

    position: absolute;
    top: 81%;
    width: 17%;
}
```